# How to setInterval Generator correctly?

Tags: javascript, generator, setinterval

**Goal:**
I want to create a generator function that is being invoked inside `setInterval()`, and `console.log` 1 to 10.

**the problem:**
In order to `clearInterval()` at the end I need a condition to check if `gen.next().done === true`.
but every time the condition runs it actualy calls another `.next()`
so so final print i get is: 
`1   3   5  7  9  undefined`

How do I set a ***done == true condition*** without calling `.next()` ?

```
function* myGen(){
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0 ; i <= 10; i++){
        yield counter++;    
    }
}

const gen = myGen();
const start = setInterval(() => {
    if(gen.next().done){
        clearInterval(start);
    } else {
        console.log(gen.next().value);  
    }
}, 1500)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You remember the object in a variable rather than calling `next` a second time:

```js
function* myGen(){
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0 ; i <= 10; i++){
        yield counter++;    
    }
}

const gen = myGen();
const start = setInterval(() => {
    var next = gen.next();             // *** Save it here
    if(next.done){                     // *** Use it here...
        clearInterval(start);
    } else {
        console.log(next.value);       // *** ...and here
    }
}, 150)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively use `for..of` loop, `setTimeout()`, `async/await` to avoid the need to check for `.done` property value

```js
function* myGen() {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    yield counter++;
  }
}

const gen = myGen();

(async() => {
  for (let n of gen) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(n);
        resolve()
      }, 1500)
    })
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the relatively new AsyncGenerator feature
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration

I think it abstracts the problem nicely (creating an iterator that sleeps in between each iteration).

```
async function* sleepGenerator(numSleeps, sleepMillis) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numSleeps; i++) {
        await sleep(sleepMillis);
        yield {i, numSleeps, sleepMillis};
    }
}

function sleep(sleepMillis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, sleepMillis));
}

(async function run() {
    for await (const iterMeta of sleepGenerator(5, 500)) {
        console.log(iterMeta);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

just, store the `nextValue`

```
function* myGen(){
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0 ; i <= 10; i++){
        yield counter++;    
    }
}

const gen = myGen();
const start = setInterval(() => {
    let nextValue = gen.next();
    if(nextValue.done){
        clearInterval(start);
    } else {
        console.log(nextValue.value);  
    }
}, 1500)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function* myGen(){
let counter = 0;
for(let i = 0 ; i <= 10; i++){
    yield counter++;    
}
}

const gen = myGen();
const start = setInterval(() => {
var genObj=gen.next();//keep next result as an object to avoid use next method twice

if(genObj.done){
    clearInterval(start);
} else {
    console.log(genObj.value);  
}
}, 1500)//I spent an hour learning this,late but get some konwledge,so,thanks.
```